# How to get alert when button clicked inside specific div - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**For html**

```
<div class='abc'>

    <button type="button">A</button>
    <button type="button">B</button>
    <button type="button">C</button>
    <button type="button">D</button>

</div>

<button type="button">X</button>
<button type="button">Y</button>
<button type="button">Z</button>
```

I want to alert when any one of the button is pressed in div having class name `abc`.

Suppose some one clicks on A or B , alert should be appeared.

Comment: `jQuery('.abc button').click(...)`

Comment: Why negative vote is given ?

Comment: @user3636511 Because obviously you didn't make any search and anyway didn't post any of your attempt, if any... Now the +1 to compensate is really unrelevant

Comment: @A.Wolff ok fine.. reverted..

Answer (score 3):

You need the selector to restrict to the buttons inside that element. Try this:

```
$('.abc button').click(function() {
    alert('foo');
});
```

If you specifically want to restrict it to the `A` or `B` buttons, you need a `filter()`:

```
$('.abc button').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == "A" || $(this).text() == "B";
}).click(function() {
    alert('foo');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `direct children` selector or you can use descendant selector('.abc  button') too,

```
$('.abc > button').click(function(){
 alert('');
})
```

Comment: Are you looking for div within .abc?

Comment: @Adil Typo in a hurry.. :\

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$(".abc").find("button").click(function () {
        alert("");
});
```

Comment: @A.Wolff Thanks, had to get creative since I went to answer it then quickly refreshed and there was a pile of answers haha

Answer (score 0):

You can select the buttons under the div by this method..

```
 $('.abc button').click(function() {
     alert('Hii');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

use attribute type selector to selects all the buttons

```
    $(".abc [type=button]").on("click",function(e){
        alert(1);
    });
```

Comment: `use selectors` what selectors...?

Comment: Can you explain your code snippet to help both the asker and future visitors to the site?

Answer (score 0):

You should delegate event to container level to use only one handler:

```
$('.abc').on('click', 'button', function(){
    alert("Well next time I'll read some basic tutos instead of posting this kind of question on SO...");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this way you can call click event of button of specific div element has assign "abc" class

```
$("div[class*='abc'] :input").click(function() {
    alert('your message');
});
```

[check my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gL9ST/)